# Conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) (ERROR)

Tags: java, sql-server, swing, sql-update, implicit-conversion

I have successfully **Inserted and Retrieved images and files stored as varbinary(max) in sql server** from java. What I'm trying to do now is to have a jframe which lets the user to **Update a document file or image**.

So far I'have typed this.

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    DBConnection db = new DBConnection();
    try {

        File pp = new File(pic);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(pp);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;) {

            bos.write(buf, 0, readNum);
        }

        person_image = bos.toByteArray();

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    try {

        File ff = new File(fileName);
        FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream(ff);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buf2 = new byte[1024];
        for (int readNum; (readNum = fis2.read(buf2)) != -1;) {

            bos2.write(buf2, 0, readNum);
        }

        docFile = bos2.toByteArray();

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    if (txt_doc.getText().isEmpty() || txt_pic.getText().isEmpty()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cannot have empty fields");
    } else {
        try {

            query = "UPDATE tourClient SET DocumentFile= '" + docFile + "',Photo= '" + person_image + "'WHERE Name= '" + combo_client.getSelectedItem() + "' ";

            PreparedStatement stm = db.getconn().prepareStatement(query);
            int val = stm.executeUpdate();

            if (val > 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Uploaded successfully!!!");
                rs.next();
            }
            db.getconn().close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**I'm getting this error--> Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query**

I saw some similar questions that were asked before, but still I cannot correct my mistake. If someone can show me how its done that would be great.

Comment: Did you try to print out the query to see what the server is seeing? As an aside - this should not be done in an event handler. It should be relegated to a swing worker, as this is potentially a long operation.

Comment: 1) "*I saw some similar questions that were asked before*" It's usually a good idea to link them so we know what didn't work for you. 2) When getting an error, post the full stack trace and mention the line it was thrown at (we don't have line numbering).